# Electrical Potential Energy in Field Quantities

Tags: electrostatics, energy, electric-fields, vector-fields, dielectric

The energy to assemble an object with volume charge $\rho_v$ and potential $V(\vec{R})$ is
$$W_e = \frac{1}{2} \int_{v'} \rho_v V(\vec{R}) dv'.$$

By Gauss's law, and a vector identity we know $ \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot D= \rho_v$:

$$W_e = \frac{1}{2} \int_{v'} \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot D V dv'$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2} \int_{v'} \mathbf{\nabla} (D \cdot V) - \vec{D} \cdot \mathbf{\nabla} V dv'$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2} \int_{S}  D \cdot V d\vec{s} - \frac{1}{2} \int_{v'} \vec{D} \cdot \mathbf{\nabla} V dv'$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2} \int_{S}  \vec{D} \cdot V d\vec{s} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{v'} \vec{D} \cdot \vec{E} dv'$$

However, I need to somehow end up at the form:

$$W_e = \frac{1}{2}\int_{v'} \vec{D} \cdot \vec{E} dv'$$

This requires some rationale for removing the surface area term... can anyone explain why this can be done intuitively and mathematically?

Comment: There are some weird steps in your computations. Beware that $\vec{D}$ is a vector, not a scalar, while $V$ is a scalar, not a vector. Your notation is a bit confusing.

Comment: As others have said, this final formula is only true given the volume in question is infinite, the reason we can pick infinity to be the volume is that for your original expression, the volume in question, is one that just encloses your charges fully, $\rho$ is zero for regions larger than the volume containing the charge, and thus the contribution is zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the argument goes that $\vec{D}$ and/or $V$ needs to vanish at infinity due to being infinitely far away from all charges. Hence, by picking the integration volume to be all of space, the integrands in the surface integral turn out to be zero and you get to your result.

If the charge distribution is infinite, the expressions will often diverge. The full mathematical details depend a bit more on which hypotheses are being made over $\rho$.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Alves's answer below, from Coulomb's law $D, E \sim \frac{1}{r^2}$ and $V\sim \frac{1}{r}$; so crudely speaking if the charges are all at finite distance (no infinite long wires, plates, etc.) then $DV \sim \frac{1}{r^3}$, so when multiplied by $ds \sim r^2 $ the surface integral goes to zero.